# Error: The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User:: differs from the current variable type (String)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am creating a SSIS package and getting the following error while extracting the data.

Error: The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::dunsId" differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

dunsId is varchar(150) in the source table which is nullable column and contains Null value.
The variable that I have created in SSIS to map it is of type string. I am basically trying to extract all he records and insert it in the destination table that contains column dunsId is varchar(150)

here is my insert query

```
INSERT INTO Parties (companyId, dunsId, companyName, companyTypeId,companyTypeName,companyStatusTypeId,companyStatusTypeName,simpleIndustryId,simpleIndustryDescription)  
values (companyId, dunsId, companyName, companyTypeId, companyTypeName,companyStatusTypeId,companyStatusTypeName,simpleIndustryId,simpleIndustryDescription)
```

Parameter mapping
[image]

variables

[image]

design

[image]

Comment: What I am trying to do is extract all the data in the first execute sql statement and store it in an object variable. I am then traversing the object in for loop container and trying to execute the insert statement in execute sql task within it. Correct me if I am going wrong anywhere

Comment: hence I have defined the uservariables and done the mappings in the execute sql task to hold the values in it before inserting

Comment: I am not very sure what is the purpose of doing that, for me, you could do in many other ways like what you are trying to do, such as single sql task `insert into select * from`, or `OLE DB source` to `OLE DB Destination`. If you have some reasons with your methods, you could put expression for that variable, which is to use `ISNULL` to convert `NULL`

Comment: Where do I set the IsNull, is if where my variables are defined or in parameter mapping etc

Comment: you need to put `ISNULL(column, 'replaced value')` from your first `execute sql task`

Comment: You mean while extracting the data which I am doing via a stored procedure. What do I replace the value with as I need null in the destination . Do I do ISNULL(dunsId,'NULL') for example

Comment: Exactly, but only if you think string `NULL` is distinguishable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Few ways to solve your problem:

1. Easiest way is change the data type from `string`  to `object`
2. From the first `Execute SQL task`, put `ISNULL` around the issue column, which will make sure the output is `string`
3. Use some alternate ways such as load from `Source` to `Destination` in `DataFlow task` or use one `Execute SQL task` with `INSERT INTO target_table SELECT...FROM Source_table` statement

**UPDATE**

as you mentioned, you are outputting the columns using `stored procedure`, then you could utilize statement `INSERT INTO target_table EXEC your_usp` instead of method `3` above

Comment: That's good amount of options . Option 3 seems simple and straightforward. Question here is I would have multiple stored procedures to execute . It's appproximately 20 now. So do I write 20 execute sql tasks

Comment: it really depends on how are they related, if one depends on another, I suggest put one inside another as nested procedure, if both are working as source, then you need use multiple sources. Also you could put your query in `OLE DB source`, and it is easier to understand when you have multiple `data flow task`, then lots `execute sql task`

Comment: I tried the option of using a  single execute sql task INSERT INTO dbo.GetParties EXEC dbo.getParties_SSIS  . I am getting errors. The first time I hadnt defined resultset property. The second time when i set as resultset property I go the error [Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score -1):

The Variable type for `dunsId` variable is STRING & you trying to assign a value for this variable `NULL` at runtime i.e your query returns `NULL` for column `dunsId` which is not supported for variable type String please declare it as type `Object`.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in my case with similar situation.