# How can I test for Excel blank cell in SSIS dataflow source Visual Basic script

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis

I need to read a collection of "forms", each of which is the first sheet in an individual Excel document. These documents are all collected together in a folder.  I pick certain cells from each sheet to form a record which is then written away to a SQL Server table for later analysis.

In my SSIS package, this is achieved with a Dataflow which uses a Script Component written in Visual Basic 2015 as the data source, connected to the SQL Server table as an ADO Net Destination.

The source script gets a list of the Excel files in the folder, then loops through each file, opens it in Excel, selects the first sheet, and assigns the values held in individual cells to the output fields, like this:

OutputBuffer.CreditPeriod = Sheet.Range("C10").Value.ToString

OutputBuffer.CreditReason = Sheet.Range("C12").Value.ToString

Everything works perfectly until the code encounters a cell that the user has left blank, at which point the assignment errors with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Obviously, I want to trap this condition and enter a substitute value for the output field.  Unfortunately, I have been unable to find a function or form of syntax that works in this situation using Visual Basic 2015 in SSIS.  All the examples I have found are for Visual Basic for Applications which has IsBlank() or IsEmpty() functions.  These don't work in VB here, and just generate errors like "IsEmpty is not declared".

The only function I have found in VB 2015 that seemed relevant is String.IsNullOrEmpty(). For example:

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sheet.Range("C13").Value.ToString) Then
OutputBuffer.CreditReasonOther = ""
Else
OutputBuffer.CreditReasonOther = Sheet.Range("C13").Value.ToString
End If

Sadly, this failed to trap the condition and the script still errored. I have also been unable to spot a property in the model which would indicate the Excel cell is blank before I try and read it and cause the error.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or does anyone know the correct method for detecting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" condition for an Excel cell in an If statement?  I've found no equivalent of the SQL ISNULL() function in VB that might've helped.

If it helps, to get the functionality I needed I used the following statements at the top of my script, copied from examples:

Imports System.IO

Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

This is a sample of the code extracted from my SSIS Dataflow source script:

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.IO
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
#End Region

Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()
        '
        ' Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
        ' For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
        '
        Dim XL As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim WorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
        Dim CreditNote As Excel._Workbook = Nothing
        Dim Sheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
        Dim Sheet As Excel._Worksheet = Nothing
        Dim CreditNoteFile As FileInfo = Nothing

        ' Get a list of Excel files in the Credit Notes folder.

        Dim CreditNotesFolder As New DirectoryInfo(Variables.CreditNotesFolder)
        Dim ListOfCreditNotes As FileInfo() = CreditNotesFolder.GetFiles("*.XL*")

        ' Initialse Excel and loop through all the Excel files in the directory list.

        XL = New Excel.Application
        WorkBooks = XL.Workbooks

        For Each CreditNoteFile In ListOfCreditNotes

            ' Ignore temporary files
            If CreditNoteFile.Name.StartsWith("~$") Then
                Continue For
            End If

            ' Open the Excel spreadsheet.

            CreditNote = WorkBooks.Open(CreditNoteFile.FullName)
            Sheets = CreditNote.Worksheets
            Sheet = CType(Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet) ' This CType is because of bug in .NET

            ' Pick values from individual cells as outputs

            OutputBuffer.AddRow()
            OutputBuffer.Filename = CreditNoteFile.Name
            OutputBuffer.AccountName = Sheet.Range("C6").Value.ToString
            OutputBuffer.CreditReason = Sheet.Range("C12").Value.ToString
            OutputBuffer.CreditReasonOther = Sheet.Range("C13").Value.ToString

            ' Close the spreadsheet

            CreditNote.Close()
            
        Next CreditNoteFile

        ' Mark the end of the dataflow
        
        OutputBuffer.SetEndOfRowset()
    End Sub
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079864/error-the-type-of-the-value-dbnull-being-assigned-to-variable-user-differs and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ssis-should-handle-null-values-from-execute-sql-ta/510407

Comment: Neither of the above suggestions are appropriate to the context and don't solve the problem (to save anyone else from having to check).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.  Ensure that you include sample data.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally discovered is that when the cell is blank then the .ToString function will error. So, you cannot do:

```
Sheet.Range("C6").Value.ToString
```

...and then test the result. What you have to do is test the cell before you do anything else, and "Is Nothing" is what you have to use as the test:

```
If Sheet.Range("C6").Value Is Nothing Then                         
    OutputBuffer.AccountName = ""
Else
    OutputBuffer.AccountName = Sheet.Range("C6").Value.ToString
End If
```

You're welcome.